# Prevent Flot Chart from repeating ticks while alignTicksWithAxis is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, data-visualization

**Flot chart** is repeating ticks on right Y axis when:

```
alignTicksWithAxis:1
```

I want to align both axes but hide repeated tick values.

http://jsfiddle.net/AUrfY/20/

Is there something in the [API](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) i have missed or i have to check thicks before painting and hide duplications.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate tick values?  Where the left and right yAxis both equal the same value?  So, in your jsfiddle above, 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `tickDecimals` option to 2 to get reasonable labels for the right y axis (see this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUrfY/21/)).
The label values are not really duplicated, but they are rounded so that they seem so.

Comment: So you have three conditions (align ticks on both axes, show no decimals and show no duplicate values) which are somewhat conflicting ... There is no simple solution for this. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUrfY/22/) is another alternative but breaks the first condition. Or is it ok?

Comment: A new try ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUrfY/23/)) which fulfills all three conditions, but looks somewhat strange: The "1" is at the position where "1.2" should be. Look for the `tickFormatter` function and the `helperTicks` array if you want to understand or reuse the code.

Comment: I have updated question ( i have changed word duplicate to repeat )
And your `tickFormatter` advice is something i was looking for!